# How search value inside an object in Redis?

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm newbie to Redis and Nodejs, I've watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S-mphgE5fA&t=918s) tutorial and i'm trying to search users by name,

Here is the object, returned from redis when i pass the id:

```
  {
    first_name: '‪john',
    last_name: 'doe',
    email: 'john@gmail.com',
    phone: '543313305',
    id: 'user001' 
   }
```

Here is the function of the search :

```
app.post('/user/search',function (req,res,next) {
let id = req.body.id;

client.hgetall(id ,function(err,obj){
    if(!obj){
        res.render('searchusers',{
            error:"user doesn't exist",

        });

    } else {
        obj.id = id
        console.log(obj);
        res.render('details',{
            user:obj, });
    }
   });
});
```

I've tried to replace the search by id  to search by first_name by doing this:

**First I've changed the field name to "first_name" instead of "id"**

```
<h1>Search Users</h1>
{{#if error}} <span>{{error}}</span>{{/if}}
 <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="/user/search">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Search" class="form-
  control">
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search">
```

**And than I've changed it in the app.js ;**

```
app.post('/user/search',function (req,res,next) {
let first_name = req.body.first_name;

client.hgetall(first_name ,function(err,obj){
    if(!obj){
        res.render('searchusers',{
            error:"user doesn't exist",

        });

    } else {
        obj.first_name = first_name
        console.log(obj);
        res.render('details',{
            user:obj, });
    }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`hgetall`](https://redis.io/commands/hgetall) method that you are using in the search function of the method looks up a hash by the key, which in this case is the user id and returns all of the fields of the hash from Redis.

There is no function to search over the fields of the hash.  If you need to be able to map from a first name to a user, you will need to manually build a secondary index using a data structure such as sets, that allows you to go from first name to the users that have that first name.